# How do we program such PHP scripts?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Sometimes we see websites that contain URLs like these:

somesite.com/123.php

somesite.com/124.php

somesite.com/125.php

the numbers before '.php' are the IDs of Mysql Query

somesite.com/123.php = somesite.com/file.php?id=123.

I noticed that these file [123.php,124.php,125.php] are not really stored in the server.

How can we do it ?

Comment: Google for apache mod_rewrite. Others servers, like IIS also have they're own modules to rewrite urls

Answer (score 6):

...using [rewriting rules](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) for apache, which normally are placed in `.htaccess` files.

Answer (score 2):

In your specific example, you'd use a rewrite rule in the .htaccess file like so:

```
RewriteRule ^/somesite\.com/([0-9]+)\.php/$ file.php?id=$1
```

Answer (score 1):

.htaccess files with rewrite rules using mod_rewrite.

A couple of links to get you started:

[A deeper look at mod_rewrite for Apache](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache/)

[URL Rewriting Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)

[A beginner's guide to URL Rewriting](http://blogs.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You have to employ some http redirects with an .htaccess file (on linux)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the mod_rewrite module in Apache (or the IIS equivalent if that's the case) and the .htaccess file.

The documentation is here if you're curious: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

And here's a sample rule for you that should do what you want (will redirect anything.php to index.php?id=anything):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```